# How do you configure i18next-express-middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, i18next

I am trying to get started using i18next with an Express server, but cannot get it working based on the examples in the docs.

My app consists of index.js (my Express server), package.json, and a `locales` directory with two translation files: en.json and es.json.

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const i18n = require('i18next');
const i18nMiddleware = require('i18next-express-middleware');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

i18n
  .use(i18nMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    lowerCaseLng: true,
    preload: ['en', 'es'],
    resGetPath: path.join(__dirname, 'locales/__lng__.json'),
    useCookie: false
  });

app.use(i18nMiddleware.handle(i18n, {
  removeLngFromUrl: false
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.t('home.title'));
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

module.exports = app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  } else {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
  }
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "i18n-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node Express server with i18next.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Shaun Scovil <sscovil@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.15.2",
    "i18next": "8.2.1",
    "i18next-express-middleware": "1.0.5"
  }
}
```

**locales/en.json**

```
{
  "home": {
    "title": "Hello World!"
  }
}
```

**locales/es.json**

```
{
  "home": {
    "title": "Hola Mundo!"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a very old configuration...following the readme backend are moved to own plugins...your code should look something like:

```
var i18next = require('i18next');
var FsBackend = require('i18next-node-fs-backend');
var middleware = require('i18next-express-middleware');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

i18next
  .use(FsBackend)
  .init({
    lng: 'en',
    saveMissing: true,
    debug: true,
    backend: {
      loadPath: __dirname + '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
      addPath: __dirname + '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.missing.json'
    },
    nsSeparator: '#||#',
    keySeparator: '#|#'
  });

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.use(middleware.handle(i18next, {
  // ignoreRoutes: ["/foo"],
  // removeLngFromUrl: false
}));
```

as a sample you could have a look at https://github.com/i18next/i18nextify/blob/master/example/server.js

and for the filesystem check out https://github.com/i18next/i18next-node-fs-backend for details

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Will try this out later today and accept your answer.

Comment: Worked well, thanks again. Here is my updated config, for anyone who is interested: https://gist.github.com/sscovil/656aef8301b11b370261d36a9b524521

Comment: `i18next-express-middleware` has been deprecated. Use `i18next-http-middleware` instead